Long long long path variable
over the years I have accumulated a very very long path  , now it is easily going above 4500 characters in { colon separated string(s)) in my windows environment path variable.
I usually have to prune the path every while , manually, a lengthy and delicate process , error prone and annoying.
I am wondering if Microsoft or someone else come up with a solution to this windows issue ?
Maybe a method or change to make the path longer !
Maybe there is a way to employ a list or an array for example rather than a string!
or even
Maybe someone got so annoyed with the problem and decided to write a script to automate the pruning, remove duplicates ( it happens!) take programs seldom used to an alternative path to be applied only when needed etc ...
if you can suggest a tool or a script that helps with this specific problem, I am very thankful
I know it is very annoying, but thanks for all your answers and suggestions

manual pruning of the path variable to remove paths no longer used, or changed
fishing out duplicate strings and removing the duplicates
using an alternative path variable that contains the path strings of the programs which are not used so often

